# How to create React components that accept color as parameter?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Assume that I want to create a customized button using react. And I'd like to have this component accept color as its properties and render itself based on the color from the properties.

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { name, color } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="my-button">
        <button type="button" className="btn">
          {name}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I inject the `color` into the button css style (border and font color)?

Comment: something like `<button style={{borderColor: color}}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like:

EDIT: Added code for border color too

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { name, color } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="my-button">
        <button type="button" className="btn" 
          style={{
             color,
             borderColor:color
                 }}>
          {name}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This might not work as 'color' is just a pure color, not a css style.

Comment: What type of object is color prop? isn't it a css valid value (like 'white', 'rgb(250,123,234)', etc)?

Comment: Yes, it's a color string

Comment: Then don't worry, there are certain valid css color strings, you can use them without any problems. See: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use inline css. Its better to have a class

```
  .btn-primary: {
      color: blue;
  }
```

And here is your button.

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { name, classNameProp } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="my-button">
        <button type="button" className={"btn "+ (classNameProp ? classNameProp : '')}>
          {name}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And you use it like this.

```
<MyButton classNameProp="btn-primary"/>
```